# Ramda compose function in typescript showing compilation error

Tags: typescript, ramda.js

I am trying to compose the `groupBy` and  `mapObjIndexed` but typescript showing compilation error on `groupBy` function.

```
const optionMapper = ( options: Option[], id ) => {
            const option = R.head( options );
            return {
                name: option.name,
                group: option.group,
                count: options.length,
                ....
                ....
            };
        };
        R.compose(
            R.mapObjIndexed( optionMapper ),
            R.groupBy( option =>  option.id )
        )( options );
```

the compilation error can be translated from German like

```
No function overload matched this call. 
The Argument of Type "[Record<never, unknown[]>]" can not be assigned to the Type "[...func: ((a: any) => any)[], f7: (a: unknown) => unknown, f6: (a: unknown) => unknown, f5: (a: unknown) => unknown, f4: (a: unknown) => unknown, f3: (a: unknown) => unknown, f2: (a: unknown) => unknown, f1: (...args: any[]) => unknown]" nicht zugewiesen werden.
```

Comment: You might want to run this by whoever writes the typing file you use.  Ramda's functions are hard to type for Typescript.  They may be able to point you to a fix.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add the relevant types for the the data passed to the composed function, and the output of each function inside it. For example:

```
const fn = compose<
  [Option[]], // A tuple of passed arguments to the function
  Record<string, Option[]>, // the output of the groupBy
  Record<string, OptionCounted> // the output of mapObjIndexed and the entire function
>(mapObjIndexed(optionMapper), groupBy(prop('id')));
```

Working example ([sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/compose-with-types-j9nk1?file=/src/index.ts:0-699)):

```
import { head, compose, groupBy, prop, mapObjIndexed } from 'ramda';

interface Option {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}

interface OptionCounted extends Option {
  count: number;
}

const optionMapper = (options: Option[], id: string) => {
  const option = head(options);
  return {
    id,
    name: option.name,
    count: options.length
  };
};

const fn = compose<
  [Option[]],
  Record<string, Option[]>,
  Record<string, OptionCounted>
>(mapObjIndexed(optionMapper), groupBy(prop('id')));

const options = [
  { id: 'a', name: 'a' },
  { id: 'b', name: 'b' },
  { id: 'b', name: 'b' },
  { id: 'a', name: 'a' },
  { id: 'c', name: 'c' }
];

const result = fn(options);

console.log(result);
```